# MomentJS changes date value when formatting?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to output a date in milliseconds and format it in the following way `'MMM d, YYYY, h:mm:ss A'`.

Using momentJS should make this process a little easier for me but I am experiencing some trouble that I don't understand for example, if I use native Javascript like so `new Date(12345);` the output is `"Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:12 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"`, If I use momentJS like so `moment(12345).toDate()` the output is `"Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:12 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"`

Okay, everything is great, so now I need to format, if I try to format this using `moment(12345).format('MMM d, YYYY, h:mm:ss A')` I get `"Jan 4, 1970, 1:00:12 AM"`

Why has my date changed from January 1st to January 4th when applying the formatting? I also tried the following and `moment(moment(12345).toDate()).format('MMM d, YYYY, h:mm:ss A')` and this also produced `"Jan 4, 1970, 1:00:12 AM"`

Any help would be appreciated as I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'d'` stands for day of the week. You should be using uppercase `D` or `DD`

```js
console.log(moment(12345).format('MMM D, YYYY, h:mm:ss A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js"></script>
```